# Constraints within RankNTypes

Tags: haskell, types

The function below doesn't type check.

```
test1 :: forall x. (Show x => x) -> String
test1 = show
```

This is because the last `->` doesn't have access to the constraint.  (This probably isn't the proper terminology, but hopefully it makes sense.)  I've been trying to find a use for type signatures similar to the above where the final `->` doesn't have access to the constraint.  But I can't think of any examples.

So my question is: Is there ever a case where we it's useful to have constraints in a type signature that the final `->` doesn't have access to?

---

Notice that `test1` is different than the rank 2 function below.

```
test2 :: (forall x. Show x => x) -> String
test2 = show
```

I'm interested in the the first case, not this case.  The reason `RankNTypes` is in the title is because that extension needs to be enabled to create the type signature for `test1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful to think of class constraints as inferred function arguments, as they desugar to functions and function application in GHC Core.

Let's desugar the type in question:

```
newtype ShowDict a = ShowDict (a -> String)
test1 :: forall x. (ShowDict x -> x) -> String
```

Or more simply:

```
test1 :: forall x. ((x -> String) -> x) -> String
```

This type isn't really useful. By parametricity, its implementations must be constant functions returning some string.

With the original non-desugared type, we can't even do anything with the `(Show x => x)` argument, since there isn't any `Show` dictionary around for our universally quantified `x`.

> So my question is: Is there ever a case where we it's useful to have
>   constraints in a type signature that the final -> doesn't have access
>   to?

This is a bit vaguely phrased, but I can argue the following: function argument types of the form `(c x => t)` (with `x` possibly quantified in an outer scope) never make sense in Haskell.

Class coherence implies that there is at most a single instance for each type, therefore abstracting over `c x` makes no computational difference whatsoever. If there is no `c x`, then the (desugared) function can never be applied, but if we already know there is a unique `c x`, then why depend on it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not that you don't have access to it, it's that the control over type instantiation is reversed: using a rank-2 type, you change who gets to pick the type.

In your example, the `test2` function gets to pick the type of its argument. So, for instance, this compiles:

```
test2 :: (forall x. Show x => x) -> String
test2 a = show (a :: Char)
```

This is because the argument `a` must literally work *for all* types that are an instance of `Show`. As a result, we can never call `test2` since we can never provide a value that can take on all possible types that are instances of `Show`.

Note that had we written

```
test2 :: Show x => x -> String
test2 a = ...
```

The *caller* of `test2` gets to pick the type of `a` and `test2` is the one that must work for all instances of `Show`.

Lets look at a slightly more useful example:

```
example :: (forall x. Show x => x -> Int) -> Int
example f = 10 * f True
```

We can see that, again, we (that is, `example`) get to pick the type represented by the `x` type variable (it *instantiates* that type variable to a certain type). Here, we are picking the type `Bool`. Here is how you might call this function:

```
ghci> example (length . show)
40
```

Here's another example:

```
example2 :: (forall x. [x] -> [x]) -> [Int]
example2 f = f [1, 2, 3]
```

We can give it any function on lists *as long as* that function cannot care about the actual values in that list. Since the function doesn't know the type of those values, it can't inspect them in any way (this property is called [parametricity](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/09/22/parametricity-money-for-nothing-and-theorems-for-free/)).

So, we can do something like this:

```
ghci> example2 reverse
[3,2,1]
```

... but not something like this:

```
ghci> let addOne :: Int -> Int
   |>     addOne a = a + 1
   |> 
ghci> example2 (map addOne)

<interactive>:33:15:
    Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘Int’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: [x] -> [x] at <interactive>:33:1
    Expected type: x -> x
      Actual type: Int -> Int
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘addOne’
    In the first argument of ‘example2’, namely ‘(map addOne)’
```

As far as practical utility goes, rank-n types are used extensively in (for instance) the `lens` library. This allows you to express the idea that a function uses a `Functor` instance without knowing which specific `Functor` instance it is (that is, it just uses `fmap` on it). Because of that, when you pass it around, you can give it any `Functor` instance you like.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I worded my question poorly and I've reworded it now.  I understand higher rank types of the form for `test2` in my original example.  But you didn't address the way the type in `test1` works, which is where my confusion is.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki I'm almost positive that, in `test1`, there is actually an implicit `forall x.` inside of the parentheses, shadowing the original `x` and making it equivalent to `test2`. Note that `(Show x => x) -> String` (without an explicit `forall`) has the same behavior and also requires `RankNTypes`.

Comment: This can't be the case because `test1 a = show (a :: Char)` does not compile.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki Oops, you're right. András Kovács explained that nicely.